# How to `vim -S` silently?

Tags: sessions

`:source Session.vim` causes some noise. Within (Neo)Vim I can simply run `:silent exec "source Session.vim"` to silence it, but how can I silence `vim -S` when I load my session from the command line?

I tried to do `vim +silent exec "source Session.vim"`, but it actually opens a buffer called `source Session.vim` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```sh
vim +silent\ exec\ \"source\ Session.vim\"
```

Maybe there is a more elegant way. EDIT: Yes there is in the comments, thanks a lot for commenting.

Comment: That `exec` is useless. `$ vim +sil\ so\ Session.vim` is enough. But the real solution would be to make sure that your session file is clean.

Comment: Also, `$vim +'sil so Session.vim'` or `$vim +"sil so Session.vim"` so you don't need the backslash escapes for the spaces. Feel free to update your answer to include the alternatives.

Comment: @filbranden I figured `vim +'sil! so Session.vim'` is perfect as it won't even throw an error when the file does not exist yet.